# Android TabWidget remove line at the bottom

Tags: android, tabwidget, divider

Sorry for my English)
My class extends `TabActivity`. How remove divider, which place after `TabWidget`? or how setup color for it?

[image]
Thanks!!

Answer (score 6):

Put `android:tabStripEnabled="false"` in our `<TabWidget />`

Comment: Strange, it's in the API docs, but my project is not recognizing it in the XML. Edit: Not in 1.6, but present in 2.2

Answer (score 1):

You need to write you own Tab Indicator selector. For this you can google for custom tab indicator or you can have a look in my post about Android tabs. I have written custom tabs so that you can customize your tab indicators. [Here](http://adilsoomro.blogspot.com/2011/06/iphone-like-tabs-in-android.html?spref=fb) is a link to my post. You can also find useful link to customize your tab in the post.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help, as I myself used this.
Try to reduce the margin of the frame layout.
ex:
android:layout_marginTop="-6px"
put the code inside the  line. AT least this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Its Work for Me Very Nicely:

Apply a custom theme to your activity, and null out the android:windowContentOverlay attribute.

Define a theme in themes.xml:

`<style name="YourTheme" parent="if you want">
  ...

  <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
  ...
</style>`

Apply the theme on your application or the activity in AndroidManifest.xml:

`<application android:theme="@style/YourTheme"
  ... >`